# Отправить файл через curl (api)

Tags: api, curl

Как послать post запрос с отправкой файла на сервер по api?  [Документация по api ресурса](https://prom.ua/cloud-cgi/static/uaprom-static/docs/swagger/index.html#/Orders/get_orders_list) .

На сайте в документации с примером "/products/import_file Импорт товаров" указан следующий curl

```
curl -X POST "https://my.prom.ua/api/v1/products/import_file" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: " -d "{ \"file\": \"string\", \"data\": { \"force_update\": false, \"only_available\": false, \"mark_missing_product_as\": \"none\", \"updated_fields\": [ [ \"price\", \"presence\" ] ] }}"
```

Вот какой curl я отправляю. Подскажите где я мог допустить ошибку?

```
curl POST https://my.prom.ua/api/v1/products/import_file -H "Authorization: Bearer МОЙ ТОКЕН" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: " -d "{ \"file\": "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Prom\выгрузки\Рабочее\1.xlsx", \"data\": { \"force_update\": false, \"only_available\": false, \"mark_missing_product_as\": \"none\", \"updated_fields\": [ [ \"price\", \"presence\" ] ] }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вчера же смотрели

вместо "file": "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Prom\выгрузки\Рабочее\1.xlsx", отправьте содержимое файла

Comment: Здравствуйте!
я ночь не спал не смог даже через php обычный get запрос сделать ) Через Curl получается спокойно гет сделать .

Comment: Вот такая ошибка вылезла когда я делал запрос который указал в примере 

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
{"error": {"status": 400, "message": "Unexpected request"}}curl: (6) Could not r
esolve host: "data"
curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:
{
 ^

Comment: А каким образом можно отправить бинарные данные?

Comment: Для начала отправьте содержимое csv файла, потом будите тестировать другие. Тут речь идет о содержимом файла а не пути к нему. Им не нужено наименование файла только содержимое

Comment: А каким образом я могу отправить содержимое сsv ? Нужно какое-то значение получить?

Comment: сохранить как C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Prom\выгрузки\Рабочее\1.xlsx в csv

Comment: про100 csv наглядно можно посмотреть

Comment: походу проще использовать не файл , а ссылку на файл

Comment: Ссылка должна быть доступна из интернета

Comment: мне важна простота, потому что это всё будет автоматизировано делатся и тут важна скорость и оптимизация

Comment: Дима на этапе начальной разработки никто не оптимизирует. Оптимизация это следующий этап когда работает плохо

Comment: Мне проще быстрей запустить потому что остался последний шаг и каждый день я теряю  из-за того что не могу запустить обновление на нескольких поставщиков.

Comment: Я могу сейчас сидеть изучать как с этим файлом обходиться и это уже будет оптимизация потому что файлом "правильней" закачивать чем ссылкой.

Comment: {"error": {"status": 400, "message": "Required parameter `url` missing"}}

Comment: Щя посмотрим думаю что-то другое

Comment: В любом случае я буду изучать то что Вы мне посоветовали касательно csv после того когда уже всё будет работать, чтоб оптимизировать. Спасибо

Comment: Я токен добавил для авторизации, чтоб можно было если что проверить запрос

Comment: Сейчас думаю может где-то скобки не поставил или еще какой-то символ

Comment: На самом деле если у вас есть json то вставьте его на странице а не в curl

Comment: Установите zoom razberyomsa быстрее пойдет

Comment: как мне там Вас найти?